# Slow Loading of Large MongoDB Database in Node JS

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, d3.js

I have created a webpage with Node JS, Express JS, Mongoose and D3 JS.

In the webpage, it contains 3 pull down menus: Department, Employee, Week.
The usage of the webpage is as follows:

1. When 'Department' is selected, 'Employee' menu will be filtered to show only those from the selected 'Department'. The same goes to 'Week' after 'Employee' is selected.
2. After the 3 menus are selected and 'PLOT' button is clicked, a line chart (using d3.js) will be plotted to show the employee working hours for the month.

***MongoDB Json***

```
{ dep: '1',
  emp: 'Mr A',
  week: 1,
  hrs: [{
          {1,8},
          {2,10},
          ...
       }]
}
```

Here are the snippets of my codes:

***routes.js***

```
// Connect the required database and collection
var dataAll = require('./models/dataModel'); 

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/api/data', function(req, res) {
    dataAll.find({}, {}, function(err, dataRes) {
        res.json(dataRes);
    });
}

app.get('*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
}
}
```

***index.html***

```
... // More codes
<div id="menuSelect1"></div>
<div id="menuSelect2"></div>
<div id="menuSelect3"></div>
...
<script src="./display.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
... // More codes
```

***display.js***

```
//Menu (Department,Employee,Week) Information is gathered here

queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/api/data")
.await(createPlot);

function createPlot(error, plotData) {
var myData = plotData;

var depData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.dep;})
        .rollup(function(v) {return v.length;})
        .entries(myData);

selectField1 = d3.select('#menuSelect1')
        .append("select")
        .on("change", menu1change)
        .selectAll(depData)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d) {return d.key;})
        .text(function(d) {return d.key;});

function menu1Change() {
    //Filter Next Menu with the option chosen in this menu
    ... // More codes
    var selectedVal = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var empData = dataSet.filter(function(d) { return d.emp = selectString; });
    ... // More codes
}   
... // More codes
```

}

Problem:
Functionally, it is working as expected. Problem is when the database is getting larger and larger, the loading of the page becomes very very slow (mins to load). I believe it should be due to the routing where all data is retrieved (.find({},{})) but I thought I need it because I am using it in 'display.js' to filter my menu options.

Is there a better way to do this to resolve the performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely necessary to send all the data to the client. In fact, I haven't seen an API with a single endpoint that returns the entire database to everyone.

It's hard to give you any specific solution not knowing how your data looks like, how large it is, how fast it grows etc. The performance issues may be related to querying the database, to large data transfer, or large JSON to parse by the browser.

In any case, you shouldn't send all your database to the client with no limits. Usually it is implemented with a number of records to skip and a maximum number of records to return.

Some frameworks like LoopBack does it for you, see:

- https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Skip+filter
- https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Limit+filter

If you're using Express then you'll have to implement the limits yourself.

To test the bottleneck, you can run the Mongo shell and try to run the `.find({},{})` query from there to see how long it takes. You can see the transfer size and time in the browser's developer tools. This may find you narrow down the place that needs most attention, but returning the entire database no matter how large it is, is already a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry, have added the JSON data example,Yes, I have already used the debugger in browser and the bottle neck is indeed returning the entire database.

Comment: Are there any other methods to get the required Dep, Emp, Mth data to insert into the pulldown menu if I don't get the whole database?